# subset the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
date            Speed
1986-01-01      0.3
....
2017-03-01      0.4
```

where date is index of data frame.i want to create a data frame only having data of 1986,2000 and 2017 without date index like

```
index   date    speed
1       1986    0.3
....
13      2000    0.5
```

Comment: If your dataframe is already indexed with a `DateTimeIndex` object, then you can just do: `df[df.index.year.isin([1986, 2000, 2017])]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your 'date' index is already a datetime dtype:

```
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.year
df = df[df['date'].isin([1986,2000,2017])]
```

...and if not, add `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` after the reset_index

Comment: i have tried it this command is not working                                                 
 df = df[df['date'].isin[1986,2000,2017]]

Comment: i am getting this error df = df[df['date'].isin[1986,2000,2017]]

TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following steps:

```
# Step one -reindex
df = df.reindex()

# Step two - convert date column to date type
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Step three - create year column using the date object
df['year'] = df.date.dt.year

# Step four - select target years
df[df.year.isin([1986,2000])]
```